# Difference between <sly data-sly-test and <div data-sly-test for sightly conditional statements

Tags: aem, sightly

I am new to sightly. Can someone please help me understand the difference between using

> <**sly** data-sly-test ="${condition}" data-sly-unwrap>

and

> <**div** data-sly-test="${condition}" data-sly-unwrap>

I am using this in AEM html. Will there be any structural impact on using the div tag for the conditional statements?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The **sly** will unwrap itself when the expression in **data-sly-test** evaluates to true, the **div** will not unwrap automatically. If you use **data-sly-unwrap** the **div** tag will unwrap too. **sly** is just a shorthand.

For example:

```
<sly data-sly-test=“true”>foo</sly>
<div data-sly-test=“true”>bar</div>
<div data-sly-test=“true” data-sly-unwrap>baz</div>
```

will render:

```
foo
<div>bar</div>
baz
```

Comment: The `false` side of the `data-sly-test` cases can be understood from the [HTL specification](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#225-test), specifically `Removes the whole element from the markup`.

Comment: Yeah, I read this article and it says that if data-sly-test="false", the whole element will be removed from the DOM, but it's not happening when I tried. 

I'm still getting the <div> displayed like this:
<div class="row" data-sly-test="false">
//some content
</div>

would you be able to tell why that's happening?